# Self redirect an .Asp page and keep the same Request variables

Tags: excel, redirect, formatting, self

Am trying to convert the content of a page to an Excel format, the problem is when I redirect the page I don't get my request variables so I found a solution that we should define a hiden variable for each request variable and then define the value after Get call. This is the code that am using now :

```
<script language="Javascript">
   function exportToExcel()
   {
     document.frm.hndExcel.value = "true";
     document.frm.submit();
   }
</script>


<form name="frm" method="get" action="LibGetStatistics.asp" ID="Form1">
 <% if Request.QueryString("hndExcel") = "true" then
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
 end if%>

 <%= GetStatistics() %>
  <input type="hidden" name="hndExcel" value="false" ID="Hidden1">
  *<input type="hidden" name="ShowOverDueBooks" value="
         <%=Request.QueryString "ShowOverDueBooks")%>" ID="Hidden2">
  <input type="hidden" name="StartDate" value="
         <%=Request.QueryString("StartDate")%>" ID="Hidden3">
  <input type="hidden" name="EndDate" value="
         <%=Request.QueryString("EndDate")%>" ID="Hidden4">*

 <a href="JavaScript:exportToExcel();"><img src='vimages/excel.gif' border=0></a>
</form>
```

The problem is when I want to use this code in other forms I need to declare a hidden variable for each Request variables. Is there any other way to generalize this code so when we post back the page we keep the same request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Again,
After some trys I found a general solution that don't use the hidden variables, we have just to use the Request.QueryString property :

```
<script language="Javascript">
function exportToExcel()
{
    document.frm.hndExcel.value = "true";
    document.frm.action='LibGetStatistics.asp?' + '<%=Request.QueryString%>';
    document.frm.submit();
}
</script>


<form name="frm" method="post"  ID="Form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="hndExcel" value="false" ID="Hidden1">
    <% if Request.Form("hndExcel") = "true" then
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    end if%>

    <%= GetStatistics() %>
          <a href="JavaScript:exportToExcel();">
              <img src='vimages/excel.gif' border=0></a>
</form>
```

I hope that should help people who will face this problem.